# Find out which PHP script using CPU

Tags: nginx, php

I need to find out which script on my server is using alot of CPU

`Nginx + php-fpm7.0`

Have tried this `ps aux | grep php` put it does only show the process with PID.. I need to see the full script path

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PHP-FPM` `slowlog` to  log requests which take more than `request_slowlog_timeout` to execute.